# Wordpress CSV Import posts with category, tag and custom field through HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, import

World, please help me with this because I'm going crazy. I am trying to import a huge csv into Wordpress since 2 days.

WP plugins are just slow, I have a big csv file so using wp plugins is not an option.

So the next solution is to import directly into the database. However, For importing through heidisql I need a script/way to assign the specific tag, category and custom field to the specific post and then import into wp_posts, wp_terms, wp_termsrelationship, wp_postmeta so that each post has the specific category, tag and custom field.

If you know Wordpress and mysql then you know how the tags, category and custom field are assigned to posts and why it can be a simple csv import.

What should I try?

Thank you

Comment: You could try and not post a link to this "highly popular" question all over the place. I saw that you posted it in the deployer and in the bootstrap rooms at Gitter.. Not very cool of you.

Comment: Yes, and he has posted it in the angularjs and meanio rooms too...

Answer (score 0):

Hire a coder to massage the data for you.

Comment: He said he wasn't even willing to pay $100.